# How does the android system in the device finds out which notification belongs to which application?

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I think that the notification data send by gcm server contains a unique identifier consisting the project id which helps in uniquely identifying a notification

Answer (score 2):

If you would like to know how to check which notification belongs to which application, you can use [`NotificationListenerService`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/notification/NotificationListenerService.html).

> A service that receives calls from the system when new notifications are posted or removed, or their ranking changed.

It contains `onNotificationPosted(StatusBarNotification sbn)` method which is triggered when new notification is posted. Using [`StatusBarNotification`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/notification/StatusBarNotification.html) object you can get information about notification, e.g. the package of the app that posted the notification when using `getPackageName()`.